# Protocol buffer `ParseFromString` in Java for parsing text format?

Tags: java, parsing, protocol-buffers

Is `ParseFromString` available in Java for protocol buffers?

The C++ version has it: [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.h)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Protocol Buffers, but does `merge`ing into a blank message do the same thing?

Comment: OK, I see there's something for `Readable`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the implementation of ParseFromString](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc) (note that `TextFormat::ParseFromString` simply calls `TextFormat::Parser::ParseFromString` on a new `Parser` object):

```
bool TextFormat::Parser::Parse(io::ZeroCopyInputStream* input,
                               Message* output) {
  output->Clear();
  return Merge(input, output);
}

bool TextFormat::Parser::ParseFromString(const string& input,
                                         Message* output) {
  io::ArrayInputStream input_stream(input.data(), input.size());
  return Parse(&input_stream, output);
}
```

You can see that `Parse` simply clears the message, then calls `Merge`. Although the Java implementation of Protocol Buffers doesn't have a `Parse` method, you can easily implement it:

```
public static void parseFromString(CharSequence input, ExtensionRegistry extensionRegistry, Message.Builder builder) throws ParseException {
    builder.clear();
    TextFormat.merge(input, extensionRegistry, builder);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For a message `A`, method `TextFormat.getParser().merge(str, builder);` does it. E.g.:

```
    AOuterClass.A.Builder buildA = AOuterClass.A.newBuilder();
    buildA.setName("Abra Kadabra");
    buildA.addPrices(3.14);
    buildA.addPrices(3.141592);
    AOuterClass.A aaa = buildA.build();

    String str = aaa.toString();

    AOuterClass.A.Builder builder = AOuterClass.A.newBuilder();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    TextFormat.getParser().merge(str, builder);

    System.out.println(builder.build().equals(aaa));  //true
```

Tested with `proto3`.