# com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException

Tags: java, json, prototype, protocol-buffers

Tried to parse bidrequest from bytes,but getting exception as follows,Have searched for long time but not able to find solution.kindly help if anyone knows...

```
    //Bidrequest json string fetched from httpRequest

    String obj = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());

    ExtensionRegistry reg = ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();                    
    AdxExt.registerAllExtensions(reg);

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getBytes(),0,obj.getBytes().length);

    BidRequest openRTBRequest =BidRequest.parseFrom(input,reg);
```

[Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tZbi.png)

Comment: Try directly BidRequest.parseFrom(request.getReader())

Comment: `BidRequest.parseFrom` is expecting binary format; you're giving it a text-formatted proto.

Comment: Have tried..but  it is not applicable for the arguments  as (BufferedReader, ExtensionRegistry) @Grigory

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you please provide details..I have tried all byteString,byteBuffer,encoded as base64..everything..but somewhere I struck..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28890646/3788176